# Bug in Unity UI OnEndDrag - pointerCurrentRaycast?

Tags: unity-game-engine

i try to determine which object is under my dragged object when OnEndDrag is called. I guess, for this reason pointerCurrentRaycast is in the PointerEventData.

For example a simple inventory system:

[image]
[image]

The power item has a simple script component with the IEndDragHandler implementation.... When i drag the item from cell1 over cell2 and the OnEndDrag event is called, there is is cell2.GO in the pointerCurrentRaycast Field of the event data... 
But, when i drag a item upwards in the hierarchy, in this example from cell1 in cell0, the item itself is in the pointerCurrentRaycast Field,...

any idea?

//remarks
i know that other ways exist to determine which object is under the pointer but i try to understand this strange OnEndDrag behavior.

Comment: This has to deal with your hierchy, the raycast returns the closest object. In the case of going over cell2, cell2 is later in the hierchy then your power therefore in that case cell2 is closer to your pointer then the powerUp, in the circumstance you go over cell0, cell1 is closer then cell0, and your Power is under Cell1 thus making him closer then Cell1, when the raycast is hit over cell0, your order from furthest to closest since you are dragging `power` is cell0, Power.

Comment: If on DragDown you made Power the first child element of Inventory, then all of your cells would be considered closer then Power.

Comment: huhu,
@Eddge thanks for the plausible and good answer :)